# filter not returning the value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

filter to fetch the partnername, its returns undefined all the time.

```
 administrationList = [
  {
    "runid": 6,
    "partnerid": 2,
    "partnername": "test admin2",
    
  },
  {
    "runid": 5,
    "partnerid": 5,
    "partnername": "test admin1"
  }
]

let val = administrationList.filter(pItem => pItem.partnerid == 7).partnername;
   console.log("###########val :"+val); //returns undefined
```

Comment: Am I wrong or you are trying to get a partnerid that doesn't exist? Of course, you also need to change the filter operator with find

Comment: it will have sometimes the value not exist too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

filter returns array not object so take first

```
let val = this.administrationList.filter(pItem => pItem.partnerid == 7)[0].partnername;
```

or use find to get object

```
let val = this.administrationList.find(pItem => pItem.partnerid == 7).partnername;
```

or use reduce

```
let val=this.administrationList.reduce(function(prev, curr) { return (curr.partnerid === 3) ? curr.partnername : prev; }, null);
```

```js
var administrationList = [
  {
    "runid": 6,
    "partnerid": 2,
    "partnername": "test admin2",
    
  },
  {
    "runid": 5,
    "partnerid": 5,
    "partnername": "test admin1"
  }
]

let val = administrationList.filter(pItem => pItem.partnerid == 7)[0]
console.log(val ? val.partnername : null) ;
val = administrationList.find(pItem => pItem.partnerid == 2);
console.log(val ? val.partnername : null) 
val=administrationList.reduce(function(prev, curr) { return (curr.partnerid === 5) ? curr.partnername : prev; }, null);
console.log(val)
```

Comment: error :  error TS1005: ':' expected. .. while using the  ? using angular 8

Comment: updated answer. you should remove ? from typescript then check snipped example

Comment: can i use it in one line. because I need to use the expression like this .administrations =  administrations.map(item =>({
          partnerid: item.adminId,
          partnername : administrationList.find(pItem => pItem.partnerid == item.adminId)?.partnername,
        }))

Comment: I updated answer. You can use reduce for one line solution. Check it please @user630209